# Undefined Method "To" for ActionDispatch::TestResponse using rspec-rails 6 in request spec

Tags: rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a Request spec that looks like this in Rails 7, Rspec-rails 6 :

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'GuestTokens', type: :request do
  describe 'GET /guest_tokens/:id' do
    context 'with a JSON format' do
      let(:guest_token) { FactoryBot.create(:guest_token) }

      it 'should return a JSON object of the guest token' do
        get "/guest_tokens/#{guest_token.id}.json"

        expect response.to render_template :show
      end
    end
  end
end
```

calling `response.to`

gives me `undefined method 'to' for #<ActionDispatch::TestResponse`

I'm not sure where I am straying away from the example in the docs:
https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec

Perhaps this is a configuration issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the expect function on the response like this

```
expect(response).to render_template :show
```

Comment: this was right... format on save was in my blind spot.